# How to isolate the two mirrormaker clusters, each link is one-way synchronization

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I want to deploy two mirror maker2 clusters, each link is one-way synchronization,connect-mirror-maker.properties config like this:

one mm2

```
clusters = A,B 
A.bootstrap.servers=... 
B.bootstrap.servers=... 
A->B.enabled = true 
B->A.enabled = false 
A->B.topics = .* ...
```

another mm2

```
clusters = A,B 
A.bootstrap.servers=... 
B.bootstrap.servers=... 
B->A.enabled = true 
A->B.enabled = false 
B->A.topics = .* ...
```

the reason I want to deploy like this is that each mirror maker cluster is close to the corresponding Kafka cluster, but after I start each mirror maker progress, only one cluster can Synchronous Data, the other doesn't work,I want the two clusters to be isolated, At present, it seems to affect each other, Has anyone encountered this problem? I need your help,

Thank you very much.

I start each mirror maker's progress, only one cluster can Synchronous Data, the other doesn't work, I want the two clusters to be isolated, At present, it seems to affect each other.

I have tried the setup with kakfa-3.1

Answer (score 0):

Your specification implies that you want to mirror all topics, including those that are already mirrored and/or internal topics.

You need to modify `A->B.topics` and `B->A.topics` in such a way that their intersection is empty.

Otherwise you run into a typical mirroring-a-mirror situation:

```
* we have a topic T in cluster A
* MM (A->B) mirrors topic T into cluster B (where it does not exist)
* MM (B->A) mirrors topic T into cluster A (where T already exists)
```